# Blazor app cannot refresh page, NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor app page, and when i go there by the link from another page, it works and i can see `h1` header with correct value, but if i will click F5 or call reloadpage method, it throws `NullReferenceException` on line with `h1` header, like item object is null. How can i avoid that behaviour?

```
...
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager
@page "/items/{id}"

...

<h1>@_item.Name<h1>

...

[Parameter]
public string Id { get; set; }

private Item _item;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _item= await ItemsService.GetItem(Id);
}

private void ReloadPage(bool forceLoad = false)
{
    MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/items/{Id}", forceLoad);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**OnInitializedAsync** is exactly what it sounds like, it's an asynchronous method. The data for **Item** may not be available when the razor component renders. You should check for nullability before trying to display it.

```
@if(_item is not null)
{
    <h1>@_item.Name<h1>
}
```

You may be able to do something like this as well:

```
<h1>@(_item.Name ?? "Not Available")</h1>
```

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handle-incomplete-async-actions-at-render)

Comment: But there is an await inside of the OnInitializedAsync while assigning to _item.

Comment: @SiddharthSeth, read this, you're incorrect in your understanding of the Blazor page life cycle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handle-incomplete-async-actions-at-render

Comment: To clarify here, the moment your Task yields with a continuation, the internal component code calls `StateHasChanged` and the Renderer has processor time to run it.  It's designed that way so you can show a "Loading" message if your async task is slow.  It runs a second `StateHasChanged` at the end of the OnInitialized/OnParametersSet code block for the final component render.